# syntaxhighlighter - Building: loadReposFromCache(...).error is not a function

Tags: javascript, plugins, gulp

I am trying to use the plugin [SyntaxHighlighter v4](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter), but I cannot get the build process to work!

Following the instructions [here](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Building), I get the following error:

```
$ ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js setup-project
[10:12:20] Requiring external module babel-register
[10:12:20] Using gulpfile C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\gulpfile.babel.js
[10:12:20] Starting 'setup-project:clone-repos'...
[10:12:20] 'setup-project:clone-repos' errored after 1.96 ms
[10:12:20] TypeError: loadReposFromCache(...).error is not a function
    at loadRepos (C:/git/syntaxhighlighter/build/setup-project.js:39:48)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:/git/syntaxhighlighter/build/setup-project.js:48:5)
    at module.exports (C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
(node:2532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\git\syntaxhighlighter\.projects-cache.json'
```

It seems not to be importing the github repository files to the `/repos/` directory. Can I do this manually somehow? Is there another way to get this to build so I can use it? Or even find the built files like in v3?

Here is the function that's failing in `build/setup-project.js`

```
gulp.task('setup-project:clone-repos', 'Clones all repositories from 
  SyntaxHighlighter GitHub organization', () =>
    loadRepos()
      .then(R.filter(repo => !fs.existsSync(pathToRepo(repo))))
      .then(R.filter(repo => repo.name !== 'syntaxhighlighter'))
      .then(R.map(R.curry(cloneRepo)))
      .then(Promise.all)
);
```

Tracing backward we see:

```
const loadReposFromCache = () => fs.readFile.promise(REPOS_CACHE, 'utf8').then(JSON.parse);
const loadRepos = () => loadReposFromCache().error(loadReposFromGitHub).then(R.map(R.pick(['clone_url', 'name'])));

function loadReposFromGitHub() {
  const request = require('request');

  const opts = {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/syntaxhighlighter/repos?per_page=300',
    json: true,
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'node.js' },
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    request(opts, (err, response) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      const json = response.body;
      fs.writeFile(REPOS_CACHE, JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
      resolve(json);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you find a fix? I am facing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @vaibhav I just used a different plugin. Prism.js works well for me.

Comment: I ended up doing the same :)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues in the build code for that project.

For the specific issue here, the Songbird wrapper on Bluebird promises doesn't seem to match up any more - hence the ".error is not a function" (on songbird, but ok on bluebird).

So replace `.error` with `.catch` or replace `require('songbird')` with `require('bluebird')`

In either case, that's just the start of your build woes...

I've added this to the project's issue tracking anyway, but here's what I did to get it to buiid:
https://github.com/karljacuncha/syntaxhighlighter/commit/dc015fa299d4d249e8518664e205a838c55372cf

Comment: Is there an alternative to this syntax-highlighter project? perhaps one that provides a straight-up bundle of JS files I can reference from a web-page instead of having to contend with an over-engineered build process?

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld You can download them form https://bartjolling.github.io/2021/04/29/syntaxhighlighter-online.html

Comment: @BartJolling this is fantastic! I managed to get syntax highlighting working again on my site, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The build broke again (April 2021). I forked the project from [karljacuncha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450141) and changed the call for `fs.writeFile` to `fs.writeFileSync`

https://github.com/BartJolling/syntaxhighlighter/commit/7dbd08203cba8ef3be72cbe1abbfb3475be19ef4

I also included other fixes I found in the larger community and I fixed the usage of the `-output` parameter as well.